# A counter example for the homeomorphism between quotient product of coproduct and the space itself

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need an example that: For sets $X,Y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, s.t $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$, and $X\sqcup Y/\sim$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, where $\sim$ means identifying the $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ if $x$ and $y$ are corresponding to the same point in $\mathbb{R}$.

My thoughts, can I consider $X=(-\infty,5]$ and $Y=[5,+\infty)$, and identify the $5$'s and identify $-\infty$ to $\infty$?(the loop is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Do you mean that we identify all the points in the intersection?

Comment: I don't understand your equivalence relation.

Comment: @YotasTrejos identify x ∈ X with y ∈ Y if and only if they correspond to the same point in R

Comment: You can not identify the infinite points since they do not exist in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are you sure that this example exist?

Comment: @YotasTrejos thanks, so do you have an example?

Comment: @YotasTrejos yes, please check http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/525-spr16/hw-01-spr16.pdf (1)-d

Comment: You can not construct this with both open or both closed sets because of the pasting lemma it implies that this quotient is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34813/discussion-between-6666-and-yotas-trejos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X=(-\infty, 0)$ and $Y=[0,\infty)$.

It is not possible to build a counterexample with $X$ and $Y$ both open (closed) because of the universal property.